# How to append dictionaries to a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have create a dictionary named `item_dict`.
After iterating the rows of a data frame, where multiple rows have the same id value, I want to append to `item_dict` a list ,and to that list to add more dictionaries as the iteration continues.

I tried `append`, but it does not append the newly created dictionaries to the list.

**This is what I want to obtain**

`{ id: [{col1:'value_row_1', col2:value_row_1}, {col1:'value_row_2', col2:value_row_2}]`

```
}


#define a dictionary to hold the id and values for all rows
item_dict = {}
count = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
   
    #extract columns of interest from excel
    idx = row['idx ']
    total_monthly_expenditure = row['total_monthly_expenditure ']
    expenditure_amount = row['expenditure_amount ']
    monthly_expenditure_per_item = row['monthly_expenditure_per_item EXP PER ITEM']
    sub_category = row['sub_category ']
    category = row['category ']
    
    #in the item_dict, add an empty list to the key if the key does not exist in item_dict
    if index not in item_dict:
        item_dict[idx] = []
    
    #create a dictionary with the columns of interest    
    columns_dict = {
        'id':idx, 
        'monthly_expenditure': total_monthly_expenditure, 
        'expenditure_amount': expenditure_amount, 
        'monthly_expenditure_per_item': monthly_expenditure_per_item, 
        'category': category, 
        'sub_category': sub_category
    }
    
    #append the columns_dict to the list of the id in the current iteration
    #given that there are multiple rows with the same id, but different values
    #we want to construct a list with all values for that id
    item_dict[idx].append(columns_dict)
    print(item_dict[idx])
```

**Actual Output:**

```
{15842: [{'id': 15842, 'monthly_expenditure': 452.0, 'expenditure_amount': 0.0, 'monthly_expenditure_per_item': 0.0, 'category': 'Food and Housekeeping', 'sub_category': 'Food '}]}

========================================

{15843: [{'id': 15842, 'monthly_expenditure': 102.0}]}
```

**What I want:**

```
{15842: [{'id': 15842, 'monthly_expenditure': 452.0, 'expenditure_amount': 0.0, 'monthly_expenditure_per_item': 0.0, 'category': 'Food and Housekeeping', 'sub_category': 'Food '}, 

{'id': 15842, 'monthly_expenditure': 102.0}

]}
```

Comment: `if index not in item_dict` might need to be `if idx not in item_dict`. If the `index` value associated with your dataframe is the default `0,1,2,...` then it will just keep resetting the list to an empty state because it isn't checking against `15842`. I assume that one remaining `15843` in the output is also a mistake, since you edited the rest?

Comment: That was the bug, I was using ```index``` instead of ```idx```. Many thanks!